# Databricks: Converting Parquet Table To Delta Table

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I was trying to convert an existing table in Databricks (storage on Azure) to Delta. Based on the information given [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/convert-to-delta.html), it's pretty straight forward and I wrote 2 `sql` statements as below to do that:

`convert to delta default.tableName`

```
convert to delta parquet.`dbfs:/path/to/storage/`
```

The statements ran `OK` as per the output message. However, when I tried to `desc` the table I found the `Provider` to be `parquet` only. And for verification I ran a `delete` operation on the table for some records which gives me the error:

```
A transaction log for Databricks Delta was found at `dbfs:/path/to/storage/default.db/tableName/_delta_log`,
but you are trying to read from `dbfs:/path/to/storage/default.db/tableName` using format("parquet"). You must use
'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table.
```

Not sure what's wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Which statement did you use? The table name version or the dbfs path version?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the path version of `convert to delta` command, it won't update the Hive Metastore. The inconsistency between the Hive Metastore and the storage will cause confusing errors like this.

If you use the table name version of `convert to delta` command, it will require [Databricks Runtime 6.6](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/6.6.html#databricks-runtime-66):

> Parquet tables that are referenced in the Hive metastore are now convertible to Delta Lake through their table identifiers using CONVERT TO DELTA. For details, see Convert To Delta (Delta Lake on Databricks). While this feature was previously announced in Databricks Runtime 6.1, full support was delayed to Databricks Runtime 6.6.

Comment: First I tried `Convert to delta` on table statement, it didn't give me appropriate result. Then I used the path conversion for parquet.

I have runtime 7.0 at the moment so it should do the job. I've been to this documentation & followed what was there. This doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue? You may need to contact Azure Databricks to help on this one.

Comment: thanks, worked for me: my problem was that first I ran `convert to delta...` with DBR 6.4, but then I re-run with DBR 8.3 - the issue was gone

Answer (score 1):

One more way to achieve this would be:

```
df = spark.sql('select * from  normal_table') # Read the non delta parquet table

df.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').save("ADLS PATH") #write with format as delta

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS delta.Table_Name USING DELTA LOCATION 'ADLS PATH-pointing to the above path'") #create a delta table pointing to the above delta path.
```